# C# Reportviewer Currency

Tags: c#, reportviewer, currency

I have a C# report viewer that runs a invoice, my problem is that the amount shows $ in stead of rand.

How do i change this to display south african rand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look within the output format property within the report designer, for the particular text box. If not, you could just use an additional label with the South African Rand symbol and put it next to your currency, and then set the amount to a normal figure with no symbol :)

Hope this helps!